# Object Oriented PHP: Loading data from DB to create objects?

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to OOP in PHP so here goes this "basic" question:

I have a table of customers:

```
Table 'customers'

id PRIMARY KEY
name VARCHAR 250
email VARCHAR 1000
is_active ENUM 'n','y'
```

In a script I need to select all the customers which are active (is_active == 'y') and send them a thank you email. There is a business class associated with the above table called class Customers.

I can write something very simple without using OOP:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE is_active = 'y'");
while($arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 send this customer a thank you email...
```

If I were to use OOP, how do I do something as simple as the above? If there are thousands of customers, do I write OO code that loads thousands of customer objects to send each one an email as below?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE is_active = 'y');
while($arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 $objCustomer = new Customer($arr['id']);   //reload what has already been read from the db??
 $objCustomer->sendThankYouEmail();
```

Am I doing something wrong (or silly) above?

Comment: This has nothing to do with OOP. Also, please stop using the outdated `mysql_*` API. It hasn't been maintained for more then 10 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't reload it from the DB but rather from the array:

```
$objCustomer = new Customer($arr);
$objCustomer->sendThankYouEmail();
```

In your Customer object you load the data from the array.

Another way to do it is to do the following (object properties should match the field names):

```
while($objCustomer = mysql_fetch_object($result, 'Customer')) {
    $objCustomer->sendThankYouEmail();
}
```

**Note:** If this is something new you are developing you should be using parametrized queries using MySQLI or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

If you really like to work OOP try using Doctrine.

Doctrine 2  maps relational databases to objects.
You could say.

```
// obtaining the entity manager
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);

$customerRepository = $entityManager->getRepository('Customer');
$customers = $customerRepository->findAll();

forLoop(){
   $customers[index]->email  // To get the email and do whatever you want with the customer object.
}
```

With things like this you just have to try and see if it works for you.